# NancyFx Model Binding & Serialization for Ember-Data

Tags: json, serialization, ember.js, ember-data, nancy

I'm trying to hook up Ember-Data to NancyFx. One area where I see some issues is in the model binding and serialization to meet the requirements of Ember-Data.

For example, on a PUT, Ember-Data sends JSON like the following:

```
{"user": {"username": "fred"}}
```

but NancyFx by default seems to prefer it as:

```
{"username": "fred"}
```

**Is there any easy way for me to get NancyFx to model bind to the way Ember-Data sends it?**

Likewise, when doing a GET, Ember-Data requires JSON like the following:

```
{ users: [{ id = 1, username = 'fred' }] }
```

but NancyFx serializers like this:

```
[{ id = 1, username = 'fred' }]
```

**Is there an easy way to change the NancyFx serialization to the format that Ember-Data expects?**

Answer (score 3):

In the put you should be able to bind to something like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

that is in your module:

```
Put["/somepath/"] = p =>
{
    var model = this.bind<Model>();
    // do your thing
}
```

and to return that structure from your GET:

```
Get["/somepath/"] = p =>
{
    return new { Users = new [] { new { Id= 1, Username = "fred" } } };
}
```

(word of caution: haven't run this, it's just from memory)

UPDATE

If you want to take control of the serialization and deserialization, that's just a matter of implementing 2 small interfaces - `IResponseProcessor` and `IBodyDeserializer`. For an example of that take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/horsdal/9517392) that shows how to implement them for protocol buffers.

Note that Nancy will automatically discover your implementations of  `IResponseProcessor` and `IBodyDeserializer` and hook them into the model binding and the serialization.

Comment: Thanks - this certainly works! One thing though - I will get a huge number of extra classes using this method. I'm wondering if I can get the deserializer to ignore that first "user" tag. I'm wondering if I am attacking this wrong though. Maybe I should be changing Ember so that it doesn't serialize the PUT message in that format.